# A question regarding Riemann Integrability

Tags: integration

Let's say that $f : [a,b] → ℝ$ is such that:

- $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,x]$ for each $x \in [a,b)$
- $f$ is continuous in $b$ (but not necessarily in $[a,b]$)

Is it true that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$?

And if we add the hypothesis $lim_{x→b} ∫_a^xf(t)dt ∈ ℝ$?

Comment: If you know for all $x \in [a,b]$ that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,x]$, and for every $\delta>0$ $f$ is bounded on $(b-\delta, b]$, this is enough to conclude Riemann integrability on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Why do you say that if $f$ it's bounded on $(b-\delta,b]$ then it is integrable?

Comment: @MarkusSteiner because you have continuity at $b$ which implies existence of the limit which implies boundedness in a neighborhood.

Comment: @John11 he asked why bounded implies integrable, not why bounded.

Comment: @mathworker21 the comment was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is bounded in magnitude (say by $M$) on $[a,b]$ and Riemann integrable on $[a,x]$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then it is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and put $x = \text{min}\left(\frac{\epsilon}{4M}, \frac{b-a}{2}\right)$. Choose a partition $P$ of $[a, b-x]$ so that $U_P - L_P < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Our partition $P'$ of $[a,b]$ will simply be $P' = P \cup \{b\}$ and observe that $U_{P'} - L_{P'} = U_{P} - L_{P}  + x(\sup_{x \in [b-x, b]} f(x) - \inf_{x \in [b-x,b]} f(x)) \leq U_p - L_p + \frac{\epsilon}{4M} 2M < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$.

Since *proper* Riemann integrability *always* presupposes boundedness, this more or less always holds.